# return logical TRUE/FALSE from try, tryCatch, or similar?

Tags: r, error-handling, try-catch

Is there a function in R that returns "FALSE" if an error is given, otherwise returns "TRUE"? Or something along these lines, or do I need to create my own by evaluating something like `ifelse(class(try(stop())) == "try-error", FALSE, TRUE)`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had to do this on occasion or two. What I did is I used `tryCatch` along these lines. This can be handy if you're doing simulations and sometimes some algorithm doesn't converge and produces a warning, but you want to ignore it, because you don't want your simulation to die while running on 100 nodes on a super computer.

```
> out <- tryCatch(stop("bla"), error = function(e) e)
> any(class(out) == "error")
[1] TRUE
```

If process goes through uninterrupted (without error), you get FALSE.

```
> out <- tryCatch(1:5, error = function(e) e)
> out
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
> any(class(out) == "error")
[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 4):

You surely would not want to use `ifelse` but perhaps this will show a more effective route:

```
> if( inherits(res <- try( stop() ),  "try-error") ){ FALSE} else{ res}
Error in try(stop()) : 
[1] FALSE

> if( inherits( res <- try( "ppp" ),  "try-error") ){ FALSE} else{ res}
[1] "ppp"
```

Now that I think about it a bit: The answer is just `inherits(tryres, "try-error")` since that does return a logical. How you decide to process it is then up to you. It is true that many times testing `class(tryres)=="tryerror` will succeed but sometimes there is more than one class returned, in which case it will not.

Comment: There can be at most one item in the test.

Comment: @Abe - `ifelse(vector of TRUE/FALSE,value to replace when vector==TRUE,value to replace when vector==FALSE)` compared to `if(single condition==TRUE) {do something} else {do something else}`

Comment: @thelatemail got it... so would it be more appropriate to convert the vector to a single condition using `any` (as done in the [answer by @Roman](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14470315/513006))?

Comment: Yes, or use inherits() which accomplishes the same goal